# Fire Event Activity REST

Tags: marketing-cloud, apexrest, journeybuilder, automationstudio

Is there any way I can trigger the journey builder event via API, the same way you do using automation.

I know you can fire event using this REST call
https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html#postEvent
but you have to send contact details/data in the same call. Salesforce have callout limits so can not use this if contacts are more than 50 where as we have more than this.

Scenario: 
I am adding multiple contacts to Data Extension via REST call which linked to event and then to journey builder.

When I finish the adding to contact data let say 2 contacts (actually some time these are in 100s), now I need to add these contacts to journey builder, so I need to fire the event.

I know you can use automation studio with Fire Event Activity and run once or schedule it and all new contacts added to Journey Builder. Rune once is manual job and minimum you can schedule is 30 minutes using two automations and we have to add to journey builder instantly or in less than five minutes.

Please guide me how or what is best way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this using the REST API, however, there are a couple of solutions here.

### Option 1: Scheduled Automation

1. Create a Scheduled Automation with a Fire Event Activity (linking to your Event Source DE).
2. Run the Automation using the SOAP API. I've documented the steps to start an automation [on this page](https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/starting-an-automation.md).

### Option 2: Triggered Automation

1. Create a new directory on your Enhanced FTP Account
2. Create a [Triggered Automation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/) with a Fire Event Activity (linking to your Event Source DE).
3. Select the directory you created in Step 1 as the watched directory in the Trigger Setup for your Automation.
4. Set the Automation to Active.
5. Copy a file (it can even be an empty file) into the FTP directory created in step 1 — you can perform this step programatically.

This will fire the Event and cause any new Contacts that have been added to the Event Source DE to enter the Interaction (providing they meet the Contact Filter Criteria defined in the Event).